Can the CLTV opcode be included in a Bitcoin wallet creation script?
I want to understand if it is possible to include an absolute locktime during the wallet generation process.
If I understand correctly, this would mean that the send function would be non-operational until the block height is reached, and any funds could not be transferred even if the private key was hacked.
I am not looking for a way to timelock individual transactions.

The terminology here is a bit confusing. A wallet is a software connecting to the Bitcoin network to track your transactions. It generates addresses, which commit to the definition of the spending conditions for your coins.
You can create a wallet which generates addresses such as received coins are not spendable until a specific date (or block height). This feature leverages the CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY opcode in Bitcoin Script.
This feature is available today on the Bitcoin Core wallet, although it requires to be comfortable with typing commands. It is made available in the wallet through the use of Miniscript Output Descriptor.
A related feature is to have a spending condition which is not available until a period of time has passed after receiving the coin (as opposed to a specific fixed date). This has the advantage of not putting an "expiration date" on your wallet. This feature is available in the Liana wallet which is more approachable to a newcomer than setting up Miniscript descriptors directly on the Bitcoin Core wallet.

Disclosure: i created and maintained Liana at Wizardsardine, a company of which i'm still a shareholder.
